# How do deserialize JSON using JSON.NET & c# without getting null properties

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am using JSON.NET to deserialize but having the object instantiated with all its properties set to null.

JSON

```
{
    "verify-purchase":
    {
        "item_name":"Pipeline.NET Task Scheduler",
        "item_id":"1111111",
        "created_at":"Wed Jun 12 15:56:02 +1000 2013",
        "buyer":"xxxxxxxx",
        "licence":"Regular License"
    }
}
```

C# Class

```
public class VerifyPurchase
{
     [JsonProperty("item_name")]
     public string ItemName { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("item_id")]
     public string ItemId { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("created_at")]
     public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("buyer")]
     public string Buyer { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("licence")]
     public string Licence { get; set; }
}
```

C# Deserialization

```
var purchase = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerifyPurchase>(jsonText);
```

This seems simple enough. What is going wrong here to result in NULL properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a wrapper class allowing you to specify the `verify-purchase` property:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("verify-purchase")]
    public VerifyPurchase Purchase { get; set; }
}
```

that you would deserialize:

```
var wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(jsonText);
VerifyPurchase purchase = wrapper.Purchase;
// the purchase.* properties should be assigned at this stage
```

Comment: I tried the wrapper before but didn't include the attribute. Thanks for the solution.